# Throwing error while parsing- org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Invalid escape sequence in JSON string '\Q'

Tags: java, mongodb, gson, mongo-java-driver, org.json

I need to parse json string to Document to store in mongodb.
When i am going to parse json string using Document.parse(jsonStr), if jsonstr contains "\" then it will throw  org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Invalid escape sequence in JSON string '\Q'.

## Sample Code

```
String json="{'a':'as\\Qd'}"; //Json String with "\"
Document doc = Document.parse(json);//Going to parse jsonstring which has "\"
System.out.println(doc.toJson());
```

Comment: Actually if you try with "{'a':'as\\td'}" it's working, Seem like specific case for mongo

Comment: yes It's because \t consider as escape character but when we use other characters like {'a':'as\\qd'}, {'a':'as\\jd'}, {'a':'as\\pd'}, etc then it's failed.

Comment: Even I have tried below things it's working                                                      String json1="{\"name\": \"Admin\",\"age\": 36,\"rights\": [\"as\bd2\", \"as\bd1\", \"sf\t1\"]}";  
Document d = Document.parse(json1);                                                                      But when i replaces \b with \s then it gives compile time error saying Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )